# Reusing Ontologies with different naming convention (Camel Case Convention and Underscore Convention)

Tags: owl, ontology

I have created an Ontology for HVAC ( heating, ventilation, and air conditioning) fault detection and diagnostics. Presently I am trying to reuse existing classes from other ontologies namely BrickSchema available at https://brickschema.org/ontology and DigitalBuilding ontologies available at https://github.com/google/digitalbuildings to follow best practices for creating ontologies.

Specifically, I have used the class Location from Brick and State from digital buildings. The issue that I face now is that these two ontologies have defined their classes in different naming conventions.

I am aware that it is not advised to use multiple conventions as the inconsistencies in naming conventions can impair the readability and navigability of ontology class hierarchies, and even hinder their alignment and integration.

Now my concern is that manually changing the convention of reused class from digital buildings (since I am using Camel case convention) is considered as reusing ontologies or there is any specific guidelines to be followed in such cases.

Comment: Given that you're reusing ontologies that already exist, I would pick a convention for any new classes and properties you create and reuse the existing classes and properties as they are - otherwise you'd just be compounding the difficulties arising from different conventions by adding new names for existing classes, while the original authors and other ontologists reusing their content might be sticking to existing names, or introducing other yet different names.